# Create a dynamic numbered list based on Milestone/Tasks/Subtasks

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, project

I would like to create a formula based number list dependent on if a line item is classified as a Milestone, Task or Subtask.

The manual output would look as such:

```
1     Milestone
1.1   Task
1.1.1 Subtask
```

The formula needs to be dynamic enough to handle situations when there are multiple tasks (but no subtasks) or a scenario when numerous subtasks are created and a new task is created.  Example below

```
1 Milestone
1.1  Task
1.2  Task
1.3  Task
1.3.1 Subtask
1.3.2 Subtask
1.3.3 Subtask
1.4   Task
2    Milestone
```

I have tried the following, which attempts to account for when a value is above 10:

```
=IF(B10="milestone",IF(A9<10,LEFT(A9)+1,LEFT(A9,2)+1),IF(B10="Task",IF(B9="Milestone",A9+0.1,IF(B9="subtask",IF(LEFT(A9,1)<=9,A9+0.1,LEFT(A9,4)+0.1),A9+0.1)),IF(B10="subtask",IF(B9="subTask",IF(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A9,1))<=9,LEFT(A9,4)&RIGHT(A9,1)+1,0),A9&"."&1))))
```

I have also tried:

```
=IF(B39="milestone",IF(A38<10,LEFT(A38)+1,LEFT(A38,2)+1),IF(B39="Task",IF(B38="Milestone",A38+0.1,IF(B38="subtask",IF(LEFT(A38,1)<=9,A38+0.1,LEFT(A38,4)+0.1),A38+0.1)),IF(B39="subtask",IF(B38="Task",IF(A38<=9,LEFT(A38,4)&"."&1,LEFT(A38,5)&"."&1),LEFT(A38,5)&RIGHT(A38,1)+1))))
```

In both instances I run into the a #Value! error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Office 365 Excel we can use TEXTSPLIT and TEXTJOIN to pull apart and put back together.  Putting that with BYCOL we can change just the one we want:

```
=LET(
    tp,B2,
    ref,A1,
    clms,MATCH(tp,{"Milestone","Task","Subtask"},0),
    TEXTJOIN(".",TRUE,BYCOL(SEQUENCE(,clms),LAMBDA(a,IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(ref,"."),0,a)+0,0)+IF(a=clms,1,0)))))
```

Note that this refers to the row above it, so it needs to start in at least the 2nd row.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following is an array formula that spills the entire output, based in input range named `A`:

```
=LET(A,A1:A10, types,{"Milestone","Task","Subtask"}, seq,{1,2,3},
 tri,N({1;2;3}>=seq), n,SCAN("0.0.0",A,LAMBDA(ac,aa,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(ac,"."), 
  idx, XMATCH(aa, types), TEXTJOIN(".",,x * INDEX(tri,idx,) + N(seq=idx))))), 
 SUBSTITUTE(n,".0",""))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

We do the cumulative sum for each level on each iteration, taking the last accumulator value split by columns (`x`). To do the addition and reset the counter properly we use the following calculation:

```
x * INDEX(tri,idx,) + N(seq=idx)
```

where `idx` represents the index position of the level found in `types`. The name `tri`, is the lower unit triangular matrix.

Finally, we remove the zero counts via `SUBSTITUTE`. **Be careful**, if you don't respect the order of the levels you get the wrong result. For example if after a `Milestone` you put a `Substack` instead of a `Task`. If you keep the zero count you can prevent this, but then the output won't be as you want. I would recommend to add a conditional formatting rule, that highlights this situation.

For the general case of `m`-levels, you can use the following formula and update `types` accordingly:

```
=LET(A,A1:A10, m,3, types,{"Milestone","Task","Subtask"}, seq,SEQUENCE(,m),
 tri,N(TOCOL(seq)>=seq), n,SCAN("0.0.0",A,LAMBDA(ac,aa,LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(ac,"."), 
  idx, XMATCH(aa, types), TEXTJOIN(".",,x * INDEX(tri,idx,) + N(seq=idx))))), 
 SUBSTITUTE(n,".0",""))
```

Comment: Hi David - thanks for the response! - I would actually be defining the Milestone/Task/Subtask before creating the numbered list.  The application would be for various project management lists that may result in more or less items being added. Your result is a very interesting take on the question as well! Much appreciated.  Given, the change in parameters, how would you consider solving for the dynamic number listing?